# WWW::Mechanize and wide character warning

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

When I trying to download some HTML file with the code below:

```
$mech->get($link)
$mech->save_content("file.html");
```

I get the warning:

```
Wide character in print at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm line 2040.
```

Could someone explain how I can repair this warning?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to ensure that the output filehandles are opened with the proper encoding.

From a brief glance at the docs, it doesn't look like Mech has configurable encodings for saved files, so you can grab the content and save it yourself:

```
$mech->get( $link );
my $content = $mech->content;

open my $fh, '>:utf8', $file or die "$file: $!";
print $fh $content;
```

The `:utf8` bit in the `open` will make sure that data sent to the filehandle is encoded properly as UTF-8.

Another way to do it is to encode manually:

```
use Encode;
my $content = encode 'utf8', $mech->content;

open my $fh, '>', $file or die "$file: $!";
binmode $fh;
print $fh $content;
```

Comment: This hasn't solved the problem for me.  I still get wide character warnings.

Answer (score 8):

Prior to version [1.73](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/WWW-Mechanize-1.73/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm), you had to save the content manually using the [solution posted by @friedo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8289579/166848).

Since then, `save_content()` lets you set the I/O layer that is used by Mechanize when opening the filehandle. By setting binmode to `:utf8` as follows, wide characters are written without warning:

```
$mech->save_content("file.html", binmode => ':utf8');
```